# How can i creat a char array by combine multiple char arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

How can I combine two char arrays to one char array, in c++?

I'm think it should be something like this:

```
char[5] text1 = "12345";
char[1] text2 = ",";
char[5] text2 = "678/n";

char[] Value = text1 + text2 + text3;
```

The output would be:

> 12345,678/n

I would like to send a char array via the serial port, and was wondering how I can do this.

Comment: In `c++` you shuld consider using `std::string` instead - much easier to mess around with.

Comment: Definitely agree with Adrian here.  C++ provides a "batteries included" `string` type which will easily do all of these things.  Use that type instead of char-arrays, which are nothing but trouble.

Comment: You can use `strcat`, but it is not the most efficient thing for concatenating multiple strings together.

Comment: Well, to illustrate what I mean by "nothing but trouble," in the source-code above a `char[5]` has five chars in it, thus no "terminating null byte."  Standard "C" functions will croak on that ... badly.  Whereas `std::string` will do what you want.  *(The best thing that ever happened to the "C' language was ... "++" !)*

Comment: char Value[] = "12345" "," "678/n";

Comment: You can send each array to the serial port one by one, it is the same effect as copying to one array and sending that.  Also your code contains a lot of errors

Answer (score 5):

Since you specified C++, then definitely use `std::string`:

```
std::string text1 = "12345";
std::string text2 = ",";
std::string text3 = "678/n";

std::string Value = text1 + text2 + text3;
```

If you need access to the actual characters to send to your serial port, then access them with `Value.c_str()`

By the way, your original code didn't allocate enough space for the trailing null in the char arrays. This can lead to memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ use `std::string`. It have created for specially solve problems like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text1( "12345" );
    string text2( "," );
    string text3( "678/n" );
    cout << text1 + text2 + text3;
    return 0;
}
```

but, If you want an answer **only** using `char` arrays, you can try this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char text1[6] = "12345";
    char text2[2] = ",";
    char text3[6] = "678/n";

    char combine[100];

    strcpy(combine, text1); 

    strcat(combine, text2);
    strcat(combine, text3);

    puts(combine);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use string streams:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "12345" << "," << "678/n";
cout << ss.str();
```